How can an https connection using ECH be identified with an SNI value and targeted for blocking?
The problem I'm having is that in Chrome Developer Edition 105 for Android, I have ECH turned on, using Cloudflare's DoT, and QUIC is off. When I try to access blocked websites like Human Rights Watch in mainland China, the connection gets reset. But when I use ECH to access other domain names, such as crypto.cloudflare.com, it works fine.
Apparently, the Great Firewall of the People's Republic of China detected the domain name of the website I visited, which is the SNI value in the packet, but how did it get this value? If the Great Firewall does not block connections through SNI values, how does it achieve targeted blocking?
I tried to refresh the page.But it still gets reset.

off-topic because it's not a programming question, but even with DNS over TLS and encrypted SNI, it's not that hard to determine which website you are going to simply by examining the IP address of the TCP SYN packet. If you use a VPN instead, you'll have an all-or-nothing experience, meaning either everything gets through or nothing gets through. For many people, this is preferable.
